# why can't I install watchman using brew command?

Tags: xcode, macos, error-handling, homebrew, watchman

I'm trying to run a react native app and I've been told I need to download "watchman".
When I tried to run the command `brew install watchman` it gave this error:

```
Error: The following formula cannot be installed from bottle and must be
built from source.
  python@3.9
Install the Command Line Tools for Xcode 11.3.1 from:
  https://developer.apple.com/download/more/
```

Do I need to install Xcode or I'm just missing something? Is there any easier way to install watchman?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Basically homebrew requires the Xcode command line tools. That is how it compiles things.  Just install them and move on.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind, you can try installing directly from Facebook's Homebrew Tap:

```
brew tap facebook/fb
brew update
brew install facebook/fb/watchman
```